# How can i extract data-component attribute using python web scraping

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from this url="https://stockx.com/air-jordan-3-retro-pine-green". I am trying to get the title of the item but unfortunately, whatever I do I can't seem to extract it properly using python beatifulsoup.

`product_name=soup.find_all('div',class_='css-j7qwjs').text`

but I'm getting errors like this.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\HPPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_98396/1955605631.py in <module>
----> 1 product_name=soup.find_all('div',class_='css-j7qwjs').text

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\bs4\element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   2251     def __getattr__(self, key):
   2252         """Raise a helpful exception to explain a common code fix."""
-> 2253         raise AttributeError(
   2254             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   2255         )
```

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

can anyone tell me how can I scrape it properly?

Comment: `find_all` returns a list as hinted at by the traceback. Use `find` if you wish to immediately call .text. Good practice would also be to test for None before using the accessor.

Comment: how do i test for none?